# Problem queuing animations

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
$('#gallery-listA li.thumbnail').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('chosen');
            $('')
            $('#gallery-listA li.thumbnail').not(this).addClass('notchosenA');
            $('#gallery-listB li.thumbnail').addClass('notchosenB');
            $('.notchosenB').fadeTo(500,0.0)
            $('.notchosenB').hide(300);
            });
```

The `fadeTo` and `hide` animations run in parallel instead of in succession. I could load the animations as callbacks or put them into a queue manually, but isn't jQuery supposed to queue animations automatically? Does anyone see what my mistake here is?

Comment: Try `$('.notchosenB').fadeTo(500, 0.0).hide(300);`.

Comment: @Alex thats one and the same thing

Comment: How do you know they run in parallel? They do not in my test: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/YUZ6J/

Comment: @codeninja sry i didn't understood your question fully before answering thats why i removed the answer

Comment: @Felix_Kling--scratch that. I had multiple `fadeTo` animations in the queue and for some reason they were getting executed together regardless of their position. Do you know how to fix this (meaning, have them executed according to their position in the queue)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something when the fadeTo animation completes, then put it on the completion function for the fadeTo animation.

```
$('.notchosenB').fadeTo(500,0.0, function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Also, I don't think it makes any sense to send a duration with `.hide(300)` when the object is already at zero opacity so I removed that duration.

Since you are fading to zero opacity, it's even better to just use `.fadeOut()` which will fade to zero opacity and then automatically hide the item at the end so you don't need the `.hide()`

```
$('.notchosenB').fadeOut(500);
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZrPL2/.

jQuery will queue successive animations, but `.hide()` is apparently not considered an animation so it doesn't go into the queue (which I verified in a jsFiddle).  You can see that this will queue them all to run sequentially:

```
$("#test").fadeOut(400).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(1000);
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wBbnK/

Comment: @jfriend00--I thought about using a callback, but I have more than one animation I need to queue, so using multiple nested callbacks will get messy. I was under the impression that jQuery automatically queues animations so I was wondering why it did not work (and it does not, I've checked). Any ideas?

Comment: I added more to my answer about queued animations.  Probably easiest to avoid `.hide()` and use one of the animations that ends up with the element hidden like `fadeOut()`.